# How to acces a shader's property range from C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader

I would like to make a simple UI with sliders that change properties in my shader.

I have a few properties declared in the shader like this:

```
name ("display name", Range (min, max)) = number
```

but the properties have different ranges, and the sliders are created dynamically based on the number of properties.

I would like to know if there is a way to access the range of said shader properties so that I can set a max and min value to my sliders.

Comment: Do you want this functionality inside the UnityEditor only (this should be possible indeed), or in the game itself (in that case, accepted answer is correct)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**. This is not possible. You cannot access the range min and max values in `Range (min, max)` from C#. You have two options:

**1**.Hard-code the min, max values from C# in a constant variable. Make sure that they match the values in the `Range (min, max)` function.

**2**.Hard-code the min, max values from the shader itself then use HideInInspector to hide them from the Inspector since you only need to read them.

```
[HideInInspector]
min("Min", Float) = 0
```

and

```
[HideInInspector]
max("Max", Float) = 1
```

You can now read them from C# as a `float` with the [`Material.GetFloat`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.GetFloat.html) function. Make sure that they match the values in the `Range (min, max)` function.